# How to change the style of an external React Native module

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, node-modules, external

I'm new to React Native and I'm using [this](https://github.com/injas427/react-native-fluidbottomnavigation) repository for the TabBar.

Am I able to change some styles? By default the bubble background is blue and I want to change it to something else.

In the `index.js` under `node_modules/react-native-fluidbottomnavigation` the backgroundColor is defined as `#4C53DD`.

Am I able to change it from the point I am using the TabBar?

This is my NavBar:

[image: TabBar]

This is my code in `App.js`:

```
<TabBar
          onPress={tabIndex => {
            console.log(tabIndex);
            curTab = tabIndex;
          }}
          values={[
            {
              title: 'requests',
              image: require('./assets/requests.png'),
              tintColor: 'red',
            },
            {
              title: 'requests',
              image: require('./assets/requests.png'),
              tintColor: 'blue',
            },
            {
              title: 'events',
              image: require('./assets/events.png'),
              default: true,
              tintColor: 'green',
            },
            {
              title: 'members',
              image: require('./assets/members.png'),
              tintColor: 'orange',
            },
            {
              title: 'account',
              image: require('./assets/account.png'),
              tintColor: 'yellow',
            },
          ]}
        />
```

This tintColor doesn't change the background color as you can see in the picture. I want that blue circle to be another color.

Comment: If you go at the [FluidBottomNavigation for React Native](https://github.com/injas427/react-native-fluidbottomnavigation) README page, there is an example on how to use it. There you'll see what properties the `TabBar` and it's items supporting, which among other there is the `tintColor` for both `TabBar` and items which you can use to change the color. There is no need to fork and change any Github repos. What you'll do when the component gets updated? You'll rebase your repo each time?

Comment: the tintColor changes the font Color not the background color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the property `tintColor` that you can use for both `TabBar` and every item like this:

```jsx
import TabBar, { iconTypes } from "react-native-fluidbottomnavigation";

<TabBar
    iconStyle={{ width: 50, height: 50 }}

    // CHANGE TINT COLOR HERE ---------------

    tintColor="red" // Change tint color here

    // --------------------------------------

    onPress={(tabIndex) => {
        console.warn(tabIndex);
    }}
    isRtl={ true }
    iconSize={25}
    values={[
        { title: "Home", icon: "alarm", tintColor: curTab == 0 ? "red" : "blue", default: true, isIcon: true, iconType: iconTypes.MaterialIcons },
        { title: "Home1", tintColor: curTab == 1 ? "red" : "blue", },
        { title: "Home2", tintColor: curTab == 2 ? "red" : "blue", },
        { title: "Home3", tintColor: curTab == 3 ? "red" : "blue", },
        { title: "Home4", tintColor: curTab == 4 ? "red" : "blue", },
    ]}
/>
```

If you read more carefully my answer and the README at the repo, then you'll see that `tintColor` does not only apply to tab items but also at the **`TabBar` component itself**. So, if you set `<TabBat tintColor="red" ...` you'll have red color for the bubble like this:

[image: react-native-fluidbottomnavigation]

Comment: the tintColor changes the font Color not the background color

Comment: @Soteri check the code [here](https://github.com/injas427/react-native-fluidbottomnavigation/blob/6b2743c2a2c4e8528b2c1c86a21d7bd59a79e789/index.js#L230) at line 230 you'll see that both `styles.bubble` and `styles.miniBubble` which have the `backgroundColor: "#4C53DD"` are extending `backgroundColor: this.props.tintColor`. You're mistaken. Did you try to change the tint color? Can you point out in the source code where does `tintColor` affects just font color?

Comment: please look at the changes in my question

Comment: @Soteri I'm talking about changing the `tintColor` of the `TabBar` component, not the items. Please have a look at my updated answer and the screenshot I've made.

Answer (score 0):

First get a fork form [this](https://github.com/injas427/react-native-fluidbottomnavigation), then get a clone, do the necessary changes and push it.

All good now you can install it to your app

```
npm install --save <git-url-of-your-fork>
```